# Executables from code::blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

When I create a code::blocks project I pick a directory for it to save it's files in. When i've built and ran these projects it opens then in my terminal. But now say I wanted to distribute this program to other's also on linux. What file would I give to them? The only executable I have is in a directory called debug. I can run it normally from my terminal but what with it being in a folder called debug I'm hesitant. Also will other's be able to run it? Or do I need to do something special to make it so everyone can run it? I've pasted a copy of my directory tree below

```
[user@linux MyProject]$ ls -R
.:
bin/  obj/  MyProject.cbp  myproject.cpp  MyProject.depend  MyProject.layout

./bin:
Debug/

./bin/Debug:
MyProject*

./obj:
Debug/

./obj/Debug:
myproject.o
```

Comment: There's an option to switch to a release configuration.

Comment: @chris Now you have 2 problems to solve.

Comment: @chris Thank you that helped me. Is that all I have to do and then I can pass that executable to people?

Comment: Well, you could give them the debug one if you wanted to. You could also fiddle around with compiler options.